# Storing the time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Let me quickly explain. I have an application to manage visitors.

We have a start date of the visit (a visit can only be for one day).
We can add a time for example the time of a tour, the time the group will be having lunch, the time the group will be having a presentation etc. All times will take the start date of the visit and then append the time accordingly.

Simple code:

```
   // set tour time in tour table
    $y->setTourTime($visit->getVisitDate("Y-m-d") . $tourTime);
    // can have many presentation
    $p->setPresentationTime($visit->getVisitDate("Y-m-d") . $tourTime);
```

So I have many time stamps across multiple tables. The problem I have however, if I decide to change the start date in the visit entity, then I'll have to change *all* of the timestamps across the related tables (tour guide, lectures etc.) This is *ugly*

What I would prefer is to have a visit date, such as 2010-10-10 in the visit table. And then in the lecture tables, guide tables etc. to just store the time and not the date. How would you do that? just store it as a string, i.e. "10:00"?

Thanks for any input. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several possibilities. I prefer to have datatypes that are best suited for the job. Calculating with times is best done using DATE, TIMESTAMP and INTERVAL, so I'd use something like this:

```
SQL> create table visits
  2  ( startdate              date
  3  , starttime_tour         interval day(0) to second(0)
  4  , starttime_lunch        interval day(0) to second(0)
  5  , starttime_presentation interval day(0) to second(0)
  6  , constraint visits_ck1 check (startdate = trunc(startdate))
  7  )
  8  /

Table created.
```

You can read more about the INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND datatype here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00207

And here is an example how you insert and select from it:

```
SQL> insert into visits
  2  values
  3  ( trunc(sysdate)
  4  , to_dsinterval('0 09:00:00')
  5  , to_dsinterval('0 12:00:00')
  6  , to_dsinterval('0 13:00:00')
  7  )
  8  /

1 row created.

SQL> select startdate
  2       , starttime_tour
  3       , starttime_lunch
  4       , starttime_presentation
  5    from visits
  6  /

STARTDATE           STARTTIME_TOUR       STARTTIME_LUNCH      STARTTIME_PRESENTATI
------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
17-12-2010 00:00:00 +0 09:00:00          +0 12:00:00          +0 13:00:00

1 row selected.
```

And calculating is very easy now:

```
SQL> select startdate
  2       , startdate + starttime_tour as tour
  3       , startdate + starttime_lunch as lunch
  4       , startdate + starttime_presentation as presentation
  5    from visits
  6  /

STARTDATE           TOUR                LUNCH               PRESENTATION
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
17-12-2010 00:00:00 17-12-2010 09:00:00 17-12-2010 12:00:00 17-12-2010 13:00:00

1 row selected.
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate as a time it might be better to just create two date fields.  One holds the visit date, the other holds the tour time with a generic date attached (1/1/2000 or something consistent & non-specific) -  you ignore the date portion of the tour time but can still do time-based comparisons if necessary without converting a string to a time value.